# How to plot a cumulative distribution function weighted by the values (eg how many people live in cities >1m)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset with few, very large observations, and **I am interested in the histogram and the cumulative distribution function weighted by the values themselves.**

Think of it like having a table that shows the inhabitants for each city in a region/country. *I don't care how many towns there are, I only care that, say, 20% of the population lives in towns with fewer than 10,000 people*, 10% of the population lives in large cities of more than 1 million people, etc.

Matplotlib and seaborn can calculate weighted histograms - see code below.

**My issue is with the CDF**:

- numpy.histogram with density=True returns the value of the probability density function at the bins, [so the values do not necessarily sum to 1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)
- matplotlib.pyplot.hist with density = True returns values that do sum to 1, but it also plots the histogram, whereas I just want the values to then plot a line myself (line, not histogram)
- statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution.ECDF cannot accept weights

**What I have come up with is using numpy.histogram and then rescaling myself:**

```
hist_nodens, bin_edges_nodens=np.histogram(d, 100, weights=d, density=False)
hist_nodens /= np.sum(hist_nodens)
sns.lineplot(bin_edges_nodens[1:], np.cumsum(hist_nodens))
```

**It works, but I was wondering if there are other ways?** Using matplotlib.pyplot.hist to create a plot then close it seems more cumbersome.

I have put together a toy example here. The y axis goes to 1 in chart D but not in C

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution import ECDF
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

d= np.hstack([\
              np.random.randint(100,1000,4000),
              np.arange(10000,100000,100), \
              np.linspace(200e3,900e3,20), \
              1e6,2e6,4e6
              ])

s=np.sum(d) / 1e6

d /= 1e3

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,5)

ax[0].set_title('A) Histogram - weighted')
sns.distplot( d, 100,  kde=False, norm_hist=True, ax=ax[0], hist_kws={'weights':d} )

ax[1].set_title('B) Cumulative weighted histogram')
sns.distplot( d, 100, kde=False, norm_hist=True, ax=ax[1], hist_kws={'weights':d,'cumulative':True} )

ax[2].set_title('C) Weighted ECDF \n from np.histogram dens=True')
hist, bin_edges=np.histogram(d, 100, weights=d, density=True)
hist=np.cumsum(hist)
sns.lineplot(bin_edges[1:], hist, ax=ax[2])

ax[3].set_title('D) Weighted ECDF \n from np.histogram dens=False')
hist_nodens, bin_edges_nodens=np.histogram(d, 100, weights=d, density=False)
hist_nodens /= np.sum(hist_nodens)
sns.lineplot(bin_edges_nodens[1:], np.cumsum(hist_nodens), ax=ax[3])

py_n,py_bins,py_patches=plt.hist( d,100, weights=d, density=True, cumulative=True)

ax[4].set_title('E) ECDF - not weighted')
ecdf=ECDF( d  )
x=np.linspace( min(d), max(d), num=1000 )
y=ecdf(x)
ax[4].step(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your NumPy solution is a good one. matplotlib.pyplot.hist has some other options which you may find useful. Specifically, the cumulative=True option to make it a CDF with histtype='step' to create a lineplot instead of bars.